# how git upload code,files quickly

Tags: git, file-upload, upload

May be this question is off topic but I'm interested to know How git upload code, files quickly?

Which technology they used?

I would like to implement this technology in php :)

If we upload a file from ftp it took some time but using `git push` file uploaded very fast.

Comment: GIT is open source, go look at the code on GitHub

Comment: I've had FTP uploads which were up to 10 times faster than git pushes. Are you sure you're comparing like with like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

git only sends diffs, which contains only the parts of the file that have changed.

You could use `patch` and `diff` linux commands to achieve the same things, but it's better to use git directly.

Git doesn't use some network magic that allows you to upload faster that your normal internet bandwith.